# dojo.query for xPage with multiple custom controls

Tags: dojo, xpages

I have an xPage with multiple custom controls that are the same...
Here is the source:

< xc:myCC width="450" id="ccAA" > < /xc:myCC >
 < xc:myCC width="450" id="ccBB" > < /xc:myCC >

each custom control have editBox id=inputName I want to access trough dojo.query..

These don't work:
    var item = dojo.query("*[id$='inputName']")[0];
    var item = dojo.query("#view\:_id1\:myCC\:inputText1")[0];

This works but just for first custom control:
    var item = document.getElementById("#{id:inputName}");

I want to get all inputName elements in all custom controls and set some properties/values.
Please, advise..

Comment: Encapsulate edit controls in element with some class, or set the class on CC. Then use selector like query( ".class", "#{id:inputText1}")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax is

```
dojo.query('[id$="inputName"]');
```

The selector searches for all DOM elements whose attribute *id* ends up with *inputName*.

You will receive a dojo.NodeList which allows DOM manipulations like this:

```
var items = dojo.query('[id$="inputName"]');
items.style('border','red solid 1px')
```

Comment: doesn't work at all... On page source that two fields look like this
name="view:_id1:ccAA:inputName" and name="view:_id1:ccBB:inputName"

Comment: @user3460523: I have added some informations to my answer.